# I want to execute a cygwin script from maven's pom.xml

Tags: shell, maven, cygwin

I need to execute a shell script under cygwin, because I'm under Windows.
The shell is executed but the commands arent' recognize ...
See below :

```
<build>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
                    <id>openOCD</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                        <tasks>
                            <exec
                            executable="C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe"
                            failonerror="true">
                            <arg line="${project.basedir}/make.sh" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The make.sh for the moment doesn't seem really complicated :

```
 #!/bin/sh 

export PATH=C:\cygwin\bin:$PATH
export BLA=C:\blabla
cd $BLA
mkdir testMaven
```

And maven, via Eclipse for information with the command Run As ...Maven Install :

```
 [INFO] Executing tasks

 main:
 [exec] C:bla
 [exec]       C:\Users\truc\TestSWMavensousKepler\pouet\bla/make.sh: line 6: mkdir: command not found
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Does it work if you call this directly on the command line? `C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe C:\Users\truc\TestSWMavensousKepler\pouet\bla/make.sh`

Comment: no ! Thank you, it's perhaps a good way :)

Comment: Many thank : it works fine with :

Answer (score 0):

`C:\cygwin\bin\bash make.sh` will run your linux commands you can use that to run your shell script file. Also tasks tag(`<task>`) is now deprecated you should use target(`<target>`) instead. Ideally below code should work. You can add anything you can add between `<target>` and `</target>` in a build.xml(this is used ANT).

```
<target>
    <exec executable="C:\cygwin\bin\bash">
    <arg value="${project.basedir}/make.sh"/>
</target>
```

Make sure `C:\cygwin\bin\bash make.sh` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late (1 year after you posted) but I had this same problem and decided to post a quick article on how to fix it.

In short: 
1. Create a profile for your dev environment if necessary
2. Use cmd as the executable and supply /C and the script as arguments.

Here's the article if you want: https://medium.com/@jimmysthoughts/happily-coexisting-building-with-exec-maven-plugin-on-both-os-x-and-cygwin-d9fb0c4a02cc